# It is possible to run Robospice listener in non UI thread?

Tags: android, robospice

I'm considering using robospice library. From the documentation/samples i see that requests are executed in background thread and listeners in UI thread.

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to run listeners through robospice on non UI thread?

Let's say I have requests A and B and listeners (that can be executed on robospice) in case where for e.g. request B depends on results of request A. So when A is finished, it's listener executes request B. That is ok, but in case if i want to read part of file, which is used for request B, then this is blocking UI for few ms, because listener of A is executed on UI thread.

I can solve this with using for e.g. HandlerThread, but i don't like that then UI will behave as some kind of proxy between A and B.

So, it is possible to run robospice listeners outside of UI thread?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible easily in RoboSpice.

The only way to do it would be to create a new SpiceService of your own and pass it a custom RequestProcessor with a custom [`DefaultRequestListenerNotifier`](http://stephanenicolas.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/request/notifier/DefaultRequestListenerNotifier.html).

What is your use case ?

Comment: A typical case might be: 1) I need to work with some data in a background thread. 2) I request something from my API. 3) I want to post-process the data when it comes back from RS before delivering to my main/UI thread. Yes, I could dedicate an entire RS request to this one task, but this results in messy code when I want to use RS for API requests only. (separation of concerns)